# Disable to add extra points to change the route in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

After I displayed a route in google maps from point A to point B I have the chance to add extra points to change the route from its first calculations, which is a thing that in desktop works good, but in smartphones if you drag or zoom in or out you add with the tab an extra point and all of the sudden you have a lot of extra points making some sort of a spaguetti full of lines direction, so is there a way to work this around like disable the feature to add points between  A and B, or hear the element by some listener and then delete that extra point or something like that, any suggestion or ideas would be very appreciated .

Greetings.

```
displayRoute:function(origin, destination, service,display,$zoom) {
service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidTolls: true,
    noMiddlePoint:true, //PSEUDO CODE
}, function(response, status) {
if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  display.setDirections(response);
} else {
  alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
}
```

});
  },

Greetings.

Comment: How are you configuring the DirectionsRenderer?  Do you have `draggable: true`?

Comment: Yes, draggable is set to true since  I want that people could drag the point A and B to calculate their route.

 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   draggable: true,
   map: map,
   zoom:$zoom,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
   panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
  });

Answer (score 1):

One option: add custom markers, make them draggable, re-request the directions on `dragend`.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9d4gcvpq/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];
var map = null;
var startLocation = null;
var endLocation = null;
var directionsService = null;
var directionsDisplay = null;

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3570439, -71.0928603);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  var request = {
    origin: "Kendall Square, Boston, MA",
    destination: "77 Massachusetts Ave, Cambridge, MA",
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, RenderCustomDirections);
}

function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var route = response.routes[0];
    startLocation = new Object();
    endLocation = new Object();
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
        startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
        startLocation.marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location, "start", legs[i].start_address, "green", "A");
      }
      endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
      endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
    }
    endLocation.marker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng, "end", endLocation.address, "red", "B");
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  } else alert(status);
}

var icons = new Array();
icons["greenA"] = {
  url: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker_greenA.png",
  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34)
};

function getMarkerImage(iconColor, letter) {
    if ((typeof(iconColor) == "undefined") || (iconColor == null)) {
      iconColor = "red";
    }
    if (!icons[iconColor + letter]) {
      if (iconColor == "red") {
        iconUrl = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker" + letter + ".png";
      } else {
        iconUrl = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker_" + iconColor + letter + ".png";
      }
      icons[iconColor + letter] = {
        url: iconUrl,

        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34)
      };
    }
    return icons[iconColor + letter];

  }

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, label, html, color, letter) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    icon: getMarkerImage(color, letter),
    title: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });
  marker.myname = label;
  gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    var request = {
      origin: startLocation.marker.getPosition(),
      destination: endLocation.marker.getPosition(),
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    startLocation.marker.setMap(null);
    endLocation.marker.setMap(null);

    gmarkers = [];
    directionsService.route(request, RenderCustomDirections);

  });

  return marker;
}

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great approach, I'm just going to wait a little more for any other ideas but if there is none other ideas well this will be the right one for sure, thanks for your time  an usefull workaround. Greetings.